# linear independence of exponentials

Tags: exponential-polynomials, linear-independence

Let $X$ be the set of functions $e^{p(x)}$ of the real vector $x$, where $p$ is a multivariate polynomial with $p(0)=0$.

Is any finite subset of $X$ linearly independent?  If yes, why? If no, is the answer true for other, restricted choices of $p$? (The answer is yes when the polynomials are restricted to have degree 1.)

Comment: What does applying a polynomial to a vector mean in this context?  Does it just mean applying a multivariate polynomial to a given set of values?

Comment: If these are univariate polynomials, then the set is indeed linearly independent, which is easily seen by considering the behaviour of a linear combination as $x\to\infty$ (one of the polynomials will dominate).

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: yes; corrected

Comment: Of course, as a minor matter of terminology, "$X$ is linearly independent" (for $X$ a subset of an abstract vector space) *means* "every finite subset of $X$ is linearly independent".

Comment: For an elementary proof in the univariate case [look here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908939/independence-of-exponentials)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.
If you require that no difference $p_j-p_k$ is constant (which follows from
your assumption $p(0)=0$), then $c_1e^{p_1}+\ldots+c_me^{p_m}=0$ implies that all $c_j=0$.

In fact a more general result is true: instead of polynomials one can take any
entire functions. This is called Borel's theorem.
(See, for example, S. Lang, Introduction to complex hyperbplic spaces, Springer 1987, Theorem 1
in VII, sect 1, p. 186.)

For polynomials in one variable, this is easy: look at the asymptotics,
for example when $z$ tends to infinity on an appropriate ray, and use induction
in degree of the polynomials. To obtain the same for several variables, restrict your identity onto lines in $C^n$.

Comment: I cannot find a Theorem 1 in Chapter VI, Section 1 (about the Poisson-Jensen formula in Nevanlinna theory). Please point to the page!

Comment: @Arnold Neumaier: Sorry it is Chapter VII, page 186.